# Skip and Take is generating exception in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, linq

While executing the following query I am getting the error in InnerException as

> {"Incorrect syntax near 'OFFSET'.
>   Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement.
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
>   Incorrect syntax near 'OFFSET'.
>   Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement.
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
>   Incorrect syntax near 'OFFSET'.
>   Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement.
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'."}

C# Code:

```
var db = new DigilibEntities();

List<title> titles = new List<title>();

titles = db.titles
  .Include("themes")
  .Include("subjects")
  .Include("grades")
  .Where(x => x.themes.Count() == 0 || 
              x.subjects.Count() == 0 || 
              x.grades.Count() == 0)
  .OrderBy(x => x.id)
  .Skip(10)
  .Take(10)
  .ToList();
```

Comment: FYI, you don't need to set `titles` to an empty list that just gets thrown away when you then set it to the result of your query.

Comment: `new List<title>();` is of *no use*: `List<title> titles = db.titles...`

Comment: Which data provider are you using here? What is the actual SQL statement that is generated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default EF will use the FETCH and OFFSET syntax for pagination. This syntax is not support on old versions of SQL Server. You need to set the `ProviderManifestToken` to 2008 so that EF will generate old, 2008 style syntax.

[A breaking change in Entity Framework 6.1.2 when using EDMX and SQL Server 2008/2005](http://erikej.blogspot.ro/2014/12/a-breaking-change-in-entity-framework.html)

Comment: What if I'm not using an EDMX?